# ODK xlsform design, calculate next label value based on previous yes_no response

Tags: odk-xform

I'm working on a survey questionnaire using xlsform for ODK. Where I'm stuck: I have a questions on the from like this: 21. Are you willing to pay for the service if it was offered at $100? The answers can be either **Yes**, **No**, or **Dont know**. If the respondent says **Yes**, the next Question will need to **add $20** to the previous $100 so the question should now read as: 21. Are you willing to pay for the service if it was offered at **$120**? This should continue until the respondent says **No**. How can I implement this using xlsform design?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: So far I have manually asked the question and number of times with each next question adding a 20 to the previous value i.e.21. Are you willing to pay for the service if it was offered at $100? [Yes or No] 
21. Are you willing to pay for the service if it was offered at $120? [Yes or No] .... up to a reasonable high number. The relevance column will then skip the next question when ever the respondent select No. I feel there should be a better way to implement this??

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need a repeat `select_one` loop that goes until **No** is selected. There is a way to do that through the [indefinite-repeat XLSForm](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rs6N7_BQNA80LVHyyF8jtAQRtiVlmp75erstoyOYe38/edit#gid=0).

This is an application of it to your question:

[image]

Explanation:

- The `count` variable is keeping track of how many times your form repeats your question.
- The `repeat_count` field in `loop_question` states that your `repeat` should go on if (i) the `repeat` has ran zero times, or (ii) as soon as the answer "no" is registered in `willing_pay`.
- The variable `amount` calculates the amount you should be showing in `willing_pay`.

Hope this helps.